# (SCHEME) How do I divide these list?

Tags: scheme

How do I implement this in scheme:

*INPUT: ((1 . 1) (1 . 7))

*OUTPUT: (((1 . 2) (1 . 4) (1 . 6)) ((1 . 3) (1 . 5) (1 . 7)))

basically i have one list with two elements. Each element is also a list with two elements, both integers >= 0 and < 8

I have to create this:

```
input ((a1 . b) (a1 . c)) 

output: (if (and (= a1 a2) (odd? b))
          While < b c
             (list (a1 . b+1) (a1 . b+3) (a1 . b+n)...)) 
             (list (a2 . b) (a2 . b+2) (a2 . b+4)...)
```

Comment: The relationship between input and output isn't immediately obvious -- I think you need to explain it.

Comment: < question modified >

This is a school project, i have to create Hawaiian Checkers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"Dividing the list"**

Note: `(a . b)` is not a proper list. It's a *cons* or a *pair*.
See the different handling below where *input* is a list, but *left* and *right* are *cons* es:

Given input: `((a1 . b) (a2 . c))`
left is : `(car input)`
right is: `(cadr input)`
a1: `(car left)`
a2: `(car right)`
b: `(cdr left)`
c: `(cdr right)`

**Generation of list of odd and even pairs:**

create a starter routine(called *Hawaiian* here) that splits out the input as above.  This starter will call a recursive list generator, called *Hawaii* in this example:

```
;;; ((abscissa0 . start) (abscissa1 . end )) => 
;;;    (Hawaii start end abscissa '() '()) 
;;; When abscissa0 == abscissa1
(define (Hawaiian pairs)
  (let* ((first (car pairs))
     (second (cadr pairs))
     (start (cdr first))
...
(Hawaii start end abscissa0 '() '()))))
```

As you noticed, *Hawaii* is called with two empty lists, initializers for the results: the list of odd and even pairs.

The *Hawaii* routine counts backward from finish to start  appending to the appropriate list *odds* of *evens* depending on whether the current number is odd or even. After appending, it calls itself again(with a lower count) until the current count is the start.

The first and last lines of *Hawaii*:

```
;;; start end abscissa null null => (list odds evens)
;;; odds  = (list (abscissa . start) ... (abscissa . start+2)  ...)
;;; evens = (list (abscissa . start+1) ... (abscissa . start+3) ...)
(define (Hawaii start current abscissa odds evens)
  ;; Counting backward (start <- current )
  (let((new-el (cons abscissa current)))
    (if (=  current start)
     (list (cons new-el odds) evens)
     (let* ((next...
            (elist...
              ... ))
  (Hawaii start next abscissa olist elist)))))
```

To finish the *Hawaii* rountine, add three lines(1 at each '...'):
1. Calculate *next*, the value of *current* in the next iteration.
2. Calculate *olist*: If *current* is odd then *olist* = *new-el* + *odds*; otherwise it just *odds*, again.
3. Same for *elist*. Append new-el to *evens* or just pass *evens* along depending on whether *current* is even or not.